# Pointer to reference assignment

Tags: c++

I'm a bit confused about the assignment in C++:

Q1: Why this works:

```
int *z = &x;(1)
```

while this, of course, doesn't work:

```
*z = &x;(2)
```

Q2: Same kind of question for function:

```
funct(int *z)
```

And you call it:

```
int x;
func(&x);
```

does it mean `*z=&x`?
I know I passed the address in the above case (`z=&x`). But should the two terms on two sides of the assignment should be exactly the same?

Comment: When you write `int * z`, you declare `z` to be a int pointer. `z`'s type is thus `int*`. If you dereference a pointer (that is, you use `*` __not__ in the declaration), you access whatever `z` is pointing to. And since `z` is an int pointer, `*z` is a int. Therefore the (1) is valid, since `int*` is on both sides, while (2) isn't valid because you have `int` on the left hand side.

Comment: Following Zeta's comment, if it helps at all, (2) would be valid as `int *z; z = &x;` Note the deliberately omitted indirection dereference on the second statement.

Comment: I see no references in this question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `x` is declared as an `int`

```
int x;
```

Then your first line

```
int *z = &x;
```

Says declare `z` to be of type pointer to int.  Initialize it with a pointer to the int `x`.  All good.  It type checks fine.  `z` is a pointer to an int, and so is `&x`.

But now

```
*z = &x;
```

fails because `z` is a pointer to an int, so `*z` is an int!  You can't assign `&x`, which is a pointer to an int, to an int.  That is a type mismatch.

Now in your function call question

```
void func(int *z) {...}
```

Your call

```
func(&x);
```

is fine.  It passes `&x`, a pointer to an int, by value to the parameter `z`, which is itself a pointer to an int.  Inside of `func` you do get the effect of `z = &x`.  Parameter passing by value is very much like assignment.

**ADDENDUM**

The reason you will see a value such as `&x` passed to a parameter declared with a pointer type such as `int *z` is that it allows the caller's `x` to be modified through the parameter `z`.  In other words:

```
void func(int *z) {
    *z = *z + 1;
}
```

if called like this

```
int main() {
    int x = 10;
    func(&x);
    cout << x << '\n';
}
```

will output 11.  Passing `&x` to `z` means both that `z == &x` *and* `*z == x`, or even stronger, that `*z` and `x` are now aliases of the exact same entity in memory!  Any change made to `*z` affects `x` and vice versa; the two expressions refer to the same memory location.

In pictures:

```
     +-------+                              +-------+
  z  |       |                              |       |  *z
     |   +---+----------------------------->|       | 
 &x  |       |                              |       |  x
     +-------+                              +-------+
```

Comment: "you do get the effect of `z = &x`" - correct, maybe it would be worthwhile to mention that this also means `*z == x` (and explicitly **not** `*z == &x`, which OP seems to think for some hard-to-perceive reason).

Comment: Good idea.  Added the info, with a (non artistic) pic.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *z = &x;(1)
```

delares z to be of type "`int*`"   The "* is a part of the type, and is not part of a pointer dereference -- so you are assigning `"z = &x"` and NOT "`*z=&x`"

That should alos explain why 2 does not work -- the correct statement for (2) would be

```
 z = &x;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bad rule to write

```
int *z;
```

better write

```
int* z;
```

this leads to such confusions.
Here z is variable and int* is a type, similar to float and int types. This type is called a pointer. It stores an address in memory where you variable (including pointers) can be stored.

In C++ you assign one value of a type to another. So here every there you assign z = &x. This works because &x gives you a pointer to x. That does mean an address in memory where your int x variable lays.

---

Also you should not confuse declaration of variable:

```
int* z; 
int x;
float& f; // reference variable
```

and expression:

```
*z;
&f;
```

In upper case * and & are parts of declaration, are parts of type like "short" is a part of type "short int". In lower case they are parts of expressions - operators like "+" and "-". These are completely different things, though you use same symbols for them.

Comment: Dont have enough reputation to upvote, and dont know how to accept the answer either. Srry :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write, `*z = &x;`, you are de-referencing the pointer `z`, meaning that you are trying to assign the pointee (an `int`) to the address of `x`
To assign the pointer (and not the pointee), please write  `z = &x;`

Answer (score 0):

When you write `type* z` or `type *z` the type specifier takes precedence and the '*' is a modifier of the type. Thus both `int* z` and `int *z` mean "declare z, such that z is a pointer to type int".

```
int* z = &i;  // pointer-to-int z = the address of i

int *z;       // z is a pointer-to-int
z = &i;       // pointer-to-int z = the address of i

int *z;       // z is a pointer-to-int
*z = &i;      // take the address of i and store it in integer who's address z contains
```